# Nginx multiple subdomains in local network

Tags: nginx, server, local

So this is a common question but with a twist that I have a hard time solving. I want to have multiple apps in a server (a raspberry pi to be exact) in my local network. **Not connected to the internet**. I don't have and **don't want a domain name**, however I have set up my router DNS to point from `home` to the server local IP. All of this works fine and I can access an HTTP server at `http://home`.

I want to be able to do:

- `app1.home` -> proxy to app1 in `3000`
- `app2.home` -> proxy to app2 in `3001`

and so on.

I have tried to create one server for each app. If I set `server_name` to `app1.home` (for example) it does not work.

I'm kinda lost, I have only set up basic Nginx servers and this is my first *complicated* one. How should I approach this?

Comment: As far as I know, it is not possible to set a variable in the server_name to use it as port. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No no, the `app<x>.home` means just setting 2 servers, one with `app1.home` and `app2.home`. I will edit the question and make that more clear.

Comment: You said that: _I have tried to create one server for each app. If I set server_name to app1.home (for example) it does not work._. What didn't work? What  error did you get?

Comment: When I go to `http:/app1.home` in a machine in the local network, the browser cannot find the server and the page does not load